# Is there a way to improve speed of compilation involving constexpressions?

Tags: c++, optimization, constexpr

I wrote a program that lists all of the numbers less than n that have at least 3 distinct prime divisors. Here it is

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

const int N = 1e6;
int n;
char arr[N];

int main(){
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
        if(!arr[i])
            for(int j = 2; i*j < N; j++) 
                arr[i*j]++;
    }
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 30; i < n; i++) 
        if(arr[i] >= 3) 
            printf("%d ", i);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I noticed that I can significantly improve it's speed if `arr` was ready at start of the program so I wrote this

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

template<int N> 
struct A{
    char arr[N];
    constexpr A() : arr(){
        for(int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
            if(!arr[i])
                for(int j = 2; i*j < N; j++)
                    arr[i*j]++;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    const int N = 1e6;
    constexpr auto a = A<N>();
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 30; i < n; i++) 
        if(a.arr[i] >= 3) 
            printf("%d ", i);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Program became faster, but it takes about 30 seconds to compile second version. It takes less than a second to execute first version though. Is there a way to optimize constexpression to reduce compilation time, ideally to time close to execution of the first version of the program

Comment: So how long was the execution time of the first version?

Comment: @user1316208 "It takes less than a second to execute first version though"

Comment: This won't even compile for me without special flags: https://godbolt.org/z/mtGrpJ

Comment: @Tharwen yep, it needs -fconstexpr-loop-limit=10000000 (with a number about this big) to compile

Comment: clang is a bit faster... gcc 12secs, clang 8. But this is not such improvement. But if the compiler must do the job, it needs time for it...

Comment: The same algorithm optimisation techniques that apply to runtime programs also apply to compile time programs. Memoisation etc spring to mind here.

Comment: Tldr; I moved workload from run-time to compile-time. Now, runtime is shorter and compile-time longer. Sounds reasonable somehow... ;-)

Comment: I am not sure what the issue really is aside from an academic excercise, the whole point of a `constexpr` is for the compiler to do the work at compile time so that you have a performance improvement at run time.  In general you compile once and run many times, so taking a hit at compile time once so that you gain a performance improvement for the multiple runs of your program is worth it.  You stated you get a performance gain at runtime, so I am not sure what the point of trying to "optimize" the compile time is.

Comment: Secondarily, I don't think you could really achieve your stated goal "to reduce compilation time, ideally to time close to execution of the first version of the program." You are comparing a compiler evaluating the `constexpr`, which is on par with executing a scripting language via an interpreter, to the execution time of a fully optimized compiled program.

Comment: Thirdly, another thought comes to mind regarding the fact that you have to explicitly add a compiler flag to even get the compiler to process this (`-fconstexpr-loop-limit=10000000`). This in and of itself should cause you to pause and take stock of the situation. This flag indicates that the writers of the compiler realized that compiling this type of code could be resource and time intensive and so they built in some hard limits, which you can choose to override, but by doing that you accept the consequences - longer compile time, more resource intensive, etc.